# jquery to autopopulate field with a constructed url

Tags: jquery, auto-populate

I am making this much harder than it has to be, so I am stopping and starting from the beginning.

I want to use jquery to auto populate a url field for a client.

As the client types in the info, I want to autopop the **Complete Url** field

*For example:* 
when they start typing `http://www.yahoo.com/finance` (I want that to appear, as each letter is typed, in the **Complete URL** field)
then I need the input from the **URL1** field to be added as each letter is enter then
then this `?cid=(lz)washcom(tz)`  *[I will just stick this in a variable]*
and then the value from the **url2** field

- URL = http://www.yahoo.com/finance
- url1 = tracer
- url2 = tracer_long_shore
- $holdVar = ?cid=(lz)washcom(tz)

At the end of all thism the **Complete URL** field would read:

```
http://www.yahoo.com/finance/tracer?cid=(lz)washcom(tz)tracer_long_shore
```

of course if they remove any of the data from the fields, I want it to clear from the Complete URL field

Do anyone know how to do this:

**jsFiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/YWZPR/

**HTML Code Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" width="85%">
<tr>
<td>Center Name:</td>
<td><input id="ctrName" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>URL:</td>
<td><input id="mainURL" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>url1 / url2:</td>
<td><input id="url1" type="text" size="15" /> / <input id="url2" type="text" size="15" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Complete URL:</td>
<td><input id="completeURL" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YWZPR/2/) is what you are looking for.  I'm a little unclear about all the ordering and stuff, but does this accomplish what you are trying to do?

I added this jQuery code:

```
$("input").keyup(
  function(){
        $("#completeURL").val($("#mainURL").val() + "/" + $("#url1").val() + "/?cid=(lz)washcom(tz)" + $("#url2").val());
    }
);​
```

It just creates the correct string each time that you `keyup`.  Let me know if I understood  what you are trying to accomplish correctly.

Comment: AMAZING - particularly is you knew how much code I was using - that was not work.  THANK YOU!!!!!